# Centos 7, Apache 2.4 log to /var/log/message

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, httpd

I need help with config Apache 2.4. Centos 7. Before I dont had this problem, but now I can see access log from all doamins write to /var/log/messages - But I dont wont it.

I seen httpd.conf and others, there is no mentions about log to primary syslog file. Can you help?

Thank you

**Update 1**

As requested:

**Example line:**

> May 17 09:50:06 servername httpd: *.*.*.23 - - [17/May/2017:09:50:04
>   +0200] "GET /posting.php?mode=post&f=8 HTTP/1.1" 404 12908 "http://www.****.cz/posting.php?mode=post&f=8" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
>   NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"

***grep -Ri customlog /etc/httpd/***

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
/etc/httpd/conf/vhost.conf:     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/BASE-XX-acces_log combined
/etc/httpd/conf/vhost.conf:     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/BASESSL-XX-acces_log combined
/etc/httpd/conf/vhost.conf:     CustomLog "|$tee -a /www/xxxx.net/logs/apache/acces_log" combined
```

Comment: Please share some output from `/var/log/messages`

Comment: Please paste the output of `grep -Ri customlog /etc/httpd/` too.

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: Try doing a `grep -R syslog /etc/httpd/*`. If you search Google for "apache syslog" you can see how to configure apache/httpd to send to syslog. Just reverse the process to get it to stop.  :)

Comment: Ok, with delay. I try it, but nothing about syslog in conf files :(

Comment: Nobody know? :)